# How to change the design itself in R function FrF2

Tags: r

I was trying to solve a fractional factorial experiments at a two-level question with R function FrF2. And I want to customize the design of the experiment. However it seems not possible with the FrF2 function.

Here is my plan,

```
plan <- FrF2(16, 5, factor.names=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), generators = "-ABCD")
```

When I call for the summary of the plan I will see the design.

```
The design itself:
    A  B  C  D  E
1   1  1 -1  1  1
2  -1  1  1  1  1
3   1  1 -1 -1 -1
4  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
5   1  1  1  1 -1
6   1 -1  1 -1 -1
7   1 -1 -1 -1  1
8  -1 -1  1  1 -1
9   1 -1 -1  1 -1
10 -1  1 -1 -1  1
11  1  1  1 -1  1
12 -1 -1 -1  1  1
13 -1  1  1 -1 -1
14  1 -1  1  1  1
15 -1  1 -1  1 -1
16 -1 -1  1 -1  1
```

I was looking for a way to customize this table but I just can't find it. For example, I want it to become like,

```
The design itself:
    A  B  C  D  E
1  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
2   1  1 -1 -1 -1
3   1 -1  1 -1 -1
4  -1  1  1 -1 -1
5   1 -1 -1  1 -1
6  -1  1 -1  1 -1
7  -1 -1  1  1 -1
8   1  1  1  1 -1
9   1 -1 -1 -1  1
10 -1  1 -1 -1  1
11 -1 -1  1 -1  1
12  1  1  1 -1  1
13 -1 -1 -1  1  1
14  1  1 -1  1  1
15  1 -1  1  1  1
16 -1  1  1  1  1
```

Is there a way to do it?

The reason is because I already have the response data set.

```
Run     Factor                          
    A   B   C   D   E           
1   -   -   -   -   -   1330    1330    1165
2   +   +   -   -   -   1935    1935    1880
3   +   -   +   -   -   1770    1770    1770
4   -   +   +   -   -   1275    1275    1275
5   +   -   -   +   -   1880    1935    1880
6   -   +   -   +   -   1385    1440    1495
7   -   -   +   +   -   1220    1165    1440
8   +   +   +   +   -   2155    2100    2100
9   +   -   -   -   +   1715    1715    1660
10  -   +   -   -   +   1385    1550    1550
11  -   -   +   -   +   1000    1165    1495
12  +   +   +   -   +   1990    1990    1990
13  -   -   -   +   +   1275    1660    1550
14  +   +   -   +   +   1660    1605    1660
15  +   -   +   +   +   1880    1935    1935
16  -   +   +   +   +   1275    1220    1275
```

Comment: What is the logic on your expected output ? I don't get what you're willing to do here...

Comment: And what in `?FrF2` does not work for you: "Alternatively, the user can explicitly specify a design through accessing a specific catalogued design using the design option or specifying non-catalogued generators via the generators option."

Comment: The reason is I already have the response data for this desired design. I have added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

To get what I think you wanted, I generated a plan by the following:

```
plan <- FrF2(16, 5, generators = "-ABCD", randomize = FALSE)
```

The lines of code below re-order the 5 columns as you wanted, but they retain the original run numbers on the side.

```
> planreorder <- plan[with(plan, order(E)),]
> planreorder

    A  B  C  D  E
1  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
4   1  1 -1 -1 -1
6   1 -1  1 -1 -1
7  -1  1  1 -1 -1
10  1 -1 -1  1 -1
11 -1  1 -1  1 -1
13 -1 -1  1  1 -1
16  1  1  1  1 -1
2   1 -1 -1 -1  1
3  -1  1 -1 -1  1
5  -1 -1  1 -1  1
8   1  1  1 -1  1
9  -1 -1 -1  1  1
12  1  1 -1  1  1
14  1 -1  1  1  1
15 -1  1  1  1  1
```

If you also want to change the run numbers, the following would do:

```
> rownames(planreorder) <- c(1:16)
> planreorder

    A  B  C  D  E
1  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
2   1  1 -1 -1 -1
3   1 -1  1 -1 -1
4  -1  1  1 -1 -1
5   1 -1 -1  1 -1
6  -1  1 -1  1 -1
7  -1 -1  1  1 -1
8   1  1  1  1 -1
9   1 -1 -1 -1  1
10 -1  1 -1 -1  1
11 -1 -1  1 -1  1
12  1  1  1 -1  1
13 -1 -1 -1  1  1
14  1  1 -1  1  1
15  1 -1  1  1  1
16 -1  1  1  1  1
```